# IWizardPage not appearing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an existing wizard that I am adding a page to... However, the new page is not appearing when I add it.

Here is the addPages method in the wizard.. the new page is dsPage

```
/**
 * Adding the pages to the wizard.
 */
public void addPages() {
    templatePage = new StoreBuildDetailsPage(selection, helpUrl);
    addPage(templatePage);
    jenkinsPage = new StoreJenkinsDialog(selection);
    addPage(jenkinsPage);
    dsPage = new StoreDataSourcePage(selection);
    addPage(dsPage);
    deploymentPage = new StoreDeploymentDetailsPage(helpUrl);
    addPage(deploymentPage);
}
```

And here is the new class that I created for the dsPage

```
public class StoreDataSourcePage extends  WizardPage
```

What am I doing/not doing for it not to appear?

Overriding getNextPage

```
/**
 * grabs the data from this page to pass to the next pages
 */
public IWizardPage getNextPage(){
    saveData();     
    return super.getNextPage();
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the extension? (point 2 in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html)

Comment: Have you overridden `getNextPage` in the Wizard or WizardPage or anything like that?

Comment: I have overridded getNextPage.. Adding it above.

Comment: @greg-449 The getNextPage of the previous page was causing the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!